# Expression to read XML attribute value in Logic Apps

Tags: xpath, azure-logic-apps

In a Logic Apps For Each, I am iterating over part of an XML document that has, in part:

```
<Part ref="1">
```

I want to read out the attribute value only. In this case, "1". I have tried:

```
xpath(xml(item()),'Part/@ref')
```

and I get

```
["ref=\"1\""]
```

With

```
first(xpath(xml(item()),'Part/@ref'))
```

I get

```
ref="1"
```

I have tried incorporating string() and value() functions to no avail. What is the proper way to read out just the value?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this [xpath](/questions/tagged/xpath) expression :

```
'string(//Part/@ref)'
```

Answer (score 0):

You have to use this expression in **Code View**:

```
@xpath(xml(item()), 'string(/*[local-name()=\"Part\" and namespace-uri()=\"\"]/@*[local-name()=\"ref\" and namespace-uri()=\"\"])')
```

Comment: Thank you felixmondelo. That does work for me. Specifically in code view I used:

`"@{xpath(xml(item()), 'string(/*[local-name()=\"Part\" and namespace-uri()=\"\"]/@*[local-name()=\"ref\" and namespace-uri()=\"\"])')}"`

or in designer:

`xpath(xml(item()), 'string(/*[local-name()="Part" and namespace-uri()=""]/@*[local-name()="ref" and namespace-uri()=""])')`

But, I am using as successfully the suggestion from Gilles Quenot as it is much simpler and I have to document and explain for others.

Comment: Yes, I agree - both are correct. I wish I could mark both as correct.